# Scrollbar won't show - Jscrollpane plugin

Tags: scrollbar, jscrollpane

I'm currently facing a annoying problem with the plugin jScrollPane] (demo I'm working with : tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollbarVisibility ).

I have linked all the files required in the head of my HTML sheet (js & css), but it seems I've been misssing something. Even if I'm not very familiar with JS, I already have used lot of plugins, and could always manage to make them work. But this one is tough.

I want the middle part of the left sidebar to scroll, and hide the scroll bar when it's not needed. For now it doesn't scroll.

The website I'm working on is here : http://denislefevre.com/gmapstfe1.2

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include jQuery library before you include any other JS library.

Chrome's script debugger comes in handy

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel.js:78
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.jscrollpane.min.js:11
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jScrollPane' denislefevre.com:204
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null denislefevre.com:125
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect the first answer to be the right one. Now that you're saying it, that is quite a stupid mistake I made !

Thanks a lot !